# tidyverse - delete a column within a nested column/list

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse

I have the following data:

(Note: I'm using the current github version of dplyr within tidyverse which offerse some new experimental functions, like `condense` - which I'm using below, but I think that's not relevant for my problem/question).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

dat <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:4, each = 25),
                  Q1 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  Q2 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  Q3 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  Q4 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  Q5 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  Q6 = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

I now want to calculate the correlation between Q1 to Q6 within each group, and I'm using:

```
cor_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  condense(cor = correlate(cur_data()))
```

Which gives me the correlations as a list-column (?). Within each list, the first column is called `rowname` and I want to simply delete this column from each list in a tidyverse way. How can I do this?

I already tried something naive like `select (-rowname)`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `purrr::map_df(colname, ~ select(.x, -rowname))`?

Comment: Doesn't work. `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'colname' not found`

Comment: I think @r2evans meant "colname" as a stand-in for you to fill in your actual column name, although I think it should actually be your data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion by @r2evans would work if we remove the group attribute

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
cor_dat %>%
     ungroup %>%
     mutate(cor = map(cor, ~ select(.x, -rowname)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    grp cor             
#  <int> <list>          
#1     1 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#2     2 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#3     3 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#4     4 <tibble [6 × 6]>
```

When there is a group attribute, it results in error

```
cor_dat %>% 
    mutate(cor = map(cor, ~ select(.x, -rowname)))
```

> Error: `mutate()` argument `cor` errored.
>       ℹ `cor` is `map(cor, ~select(.x, -rowname))`.
>       ℹ The error occured in row 1.
>       ✖ no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"
>       Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

which is consistent with the same behavior if we extract as a column

```
cor_dat$cor %>% 
           map(~ .x %>% select(-rowname))
```

---

Or if we want to make it shorter, it can be done within `condense` itself because `correlate` adds a `rowname` column as per the documentation

```
dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  condense(cor = correlate(cur_data()) %>%
                              select(-rowname))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Rowwise:  grp
#    grp cor             
#  <int> <list>          
#1     1 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#2     2 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#3     3 <tibble [6 × 6]>
#4     4 <tibble [6 × 6]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, it was as simple as:

```
cor_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  condense(cor = correlate(cur_data())) %>%
  mutate(cor = list(cor[,-1]))
```

Got there by trial & error. Although this only works with column positions, not names.

Comment: Sorry, edited my post. But doesn't work with names then, either.